# Spring, Angularjs. Not able to pass CSRF token with action submit (POST request). Not JSP, Not Thymeleaf

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, csrf

I'm using this in my security config:
csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

I have csrf token (X-CSRF-TOKEN) when i just navigate through the pages. And everything works fine when i make any requests by calling some method in my angularjs controller  which makes some GET or POST requests. But i don't have csrf token when i'm trying to make POST request directly from the page via 'action' (pushing submit button). I would appreciate if could share some hints about it.

```
<form id="w0" class="js_form_output" action="/output" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button type="submit" class="button button_request">Apply now</button>
</form>
```

I have 403 forbidden as a result of my POST request and it works fine when i disable csrf in security config.

I have this message in the log:
o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8090/output

I have this in the payload of request:
${_csrf.parameterName}: ${_csrf.token}

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: Read [AngularJS form Directive API - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).